# How to cast IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

Is it possible to cast `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to List<List<T>>`? I am getting an invalid cast exception if i do it so.

Thanks

Comment: So you've tried MyEnumerable.ToList()?

Answer (score 9):

The simple cast from a collection to a list is using the [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For sample:

```
var list = collection.ToList();
```

You could use Linq to get all lists in this structure, for sample:

First import the namespace to use Linq.

```
using System.Linq;
```

And try this:

```
var list = collection.Select(c => c.ToList()) // convert each collection in a list
                     .Tolist(); //last ToList to get all conversions in a single list
```

The `list` object will be of `List<List<T>>` type.

Comment: This is correct and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast it, you have to use `ToList()` to convert the `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input;
var result = input
    .Select(i => i.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Resharper gives a nice suggestion:

```
var castedList = (myEnum is List<List<T>>) ? 
    (List<List<T>>) myEnum : 
    myEnum.Select(x => (x is List<T>) ? x as List<T>: x.ToList())
```

This will remove the obsolete call to `ToList` if the enumeration already IS a list.

Comment: Now you don't do the same thing if you have a List<List<T>> as you do if you have an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>. In the first case you return a reference to the lists while in the second you make new lists. Only doing the myEnum.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList() will make new copies of everything.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad As far as I understand we do not need new lists, if the enumerations within already are lists we can take new references to them instead, why create new list?

Comment: I agree. My point was that the two paths would do different things. In one case you get references while in the other you get new lists